# Making Github pages searchable

Tags: github, github-pages, web-search

I have made a [github webpage](https://cpryan.github.io/index.html) using R studio that I'm more or less happy with. Yay! I used the [following tutorial](http://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/rmarkdown_websites_tutorial.html) to make it. Trouble is I cannot seem to 'find' it when I google it (even though I know what I'm looking for).

StackExchange::Webmasters have suggested I may need to add a `sitemap.xml`.

Question: Do I really need a `sitemap.xml`? If so, how do I go about making one using R studio, and where does it belong in my github pages directory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is Off-topic to StackOverflow since it is more suited to Webmasters.

Comment: Here is the link to [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To better explain the off-topic reason: Only programming related questions or queries about programming related tools are only allowed in StackOverflow, refer also to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for writing on-topic questions. Even though Github maybe considered as one of that tools the context of your question is about SEO which more suited to Webmasters.

Comment: My apologies. It's not clear to me where "creating a github webpage" ends and where "webmasters" (whatever those are) begin. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Enzokie Sorry about that - should I delete it then?

Comment: since you have done migrating your question to Webmasters you can delete this question to avoid further downvotes. I understand that it sounds demotivating but that's how this site works, incase you have programming question feel free to ask in this site. If you have some issue deleting this question you can contact a moderator by flagging the question and explain that you wanted to remove it since you already migrated it :)

Comment: @Enzokie no problem, Stackoverflow has saved my life a million times (one 0.01% of which have been from my own questions), and you have been entirely respectful and polite. What's demotivating is downvotes with zero explanation. Thanks for all your help. Will delete now.

Answer (score 2):

Google crawlers index the web 4 times a day (at least they used to, maybe more now).  I see you last updated your repository a month ago.

If you search `site:cpryan.github.io` Google is supposed to return the pages it has indexed.

You can also claim your site on Google's WebMaster [site](http://www.google.com/webmasters) (by putting a small file in your repo with a code Google give you) to see even more information about what Google has or maybe has not indexed.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm still confused as to why none of that appears when I search my name, defeating the purpose of a website. Thanks for your help though, and apologies for the off-topic post.